# SDL: Prevent window from showing after SDL_SetVideoMode call

Tags: c++, window, sdl

I want to create an SDL window in an existing app. The problem I encounter is that at startup, after the SDL_SetVideoMode call, a black window pops up until the remaining of my application is initialized. This is ugly and I was wondering if there was a function which controls the hide/show of this window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be such a function in SDL, however if there were, I'd likely make you see a window pop up and disappear right away, which you may also consider ugly. You'd better display some "Loading..." message in a window, or postpone SDL_SetVideoMode call to the point when your application is fully initialized. The former is better, as the user will know that he has actually launched an application and won't try to run it multiple times.